# how to find if an arraylist contains an element and add the result count to HashMap in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I have a list of workStatuses. Each workStatus has its name and time. I can do `workStatus.getName()` while iterating through every workStatus.

```
for (workStatus ws: workStatuses) {
    String name = ws.getName();
}
```

Next I have a list of names called **nameList.**

```
List<String> nameList = new ArrayList<String>();
nameList.add("Completed");
nameList.add("Failed");
```

Now I am using HashMap to count number of workStatuses each name has.So I have to

1. Iterate through workStatuses.
2. For each workStatus, find the name.
3. Check if that name exist in my nameList.
4. If yes, then increase the
   number of Workstatus for that name and put that count on HashMap.

What I have done:

```
Integer numberOfWorkStatus =0;
Map<String,Integer> hm = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
for(WorkStatus ws: workStatuses) {
                if (ws.getName()!=null && nameList.contains(ws.getName())) {
                    numberOfWorkStatus++;   
                    hm.put(ws.getName(), numberOfWorkStatus);
                }
}
return hm;
```

Can anyone suggest me if I am doing it the right way?

Comment: Your code does not seem to

"count number of workStatuses each name has",

for example `totalCount` seems to be shared for any name, or did I misunderstood?

Comment: Loris its not shared. Every name can have different number of workStatuses. That is what I want. I have changed the variable name to make it more informative for now. Does it make sense now?

Comment: I'm only saying that your code is sharing that count for every name, so it's not correct. Take a look to the answers proposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use stream API and if I get right do something like this:

```
// List<WorkStatus> workStatuses = ...
workStatuses.stream().collect(
    Collectors.groupingBy(WorkStatus::getName, Collectors.counting()));
```

as a result you will have `Map<String, Long>`

Comment: I think you need to _filter_  "ws" object with null names before collect

Comment: To comply with the OP's requirements, you need to filter for workStatuses whose names exist in namelist.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that this way :

```
for(Stirng name :nameList)
    hm.put(name, 0);

for(WorkStatus ws: workStatuses) {
    if( hm.get(ws.getName() != null)
        hm.put(ws.getName(), hm.get(ws.getName()) + 1);

}
```

hm will contains the count of each name that is exists in the workStauses.

Comment: Good answer except the second part, where you say you can do it without a condition, I don't think that's an option, because if you get a workStatus whose name is not in nameList, you'll get a NullPointerException.

Comment: yes you are right :) null pointer is every where and we should care about it :)), thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can change this to :

```
for (String str:nameList){
  if (str.contains(ws.getName())) {
    totalCount++;   
    hm.put(ws.getName(), totalCount);
 }
}
```

You cannot check for a **String** directly from a **list** and the one you put in HM should be **ws**.

Comment: changed to ws, it was a typo error. I will go through your suggestion and try it. Will update the result. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<String, Integer> hm = new HashMap<>();
for (WorkStatus ws : workStatuses) {
    if (ws.getName() != null && nameList.contains(ws.getName())) {
        hm.putIfAbsent(ws.getName(), 0);
        hm.put(ws.getName(), hm.get(ws.getName()) + 1);
    }
}
```